# Pandas join two dataframes and keep data from one dataset if some rows are not present in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["name_"+str(i) for i in range(10)], list(range(10))]).transpose()
df1.columns = ["Name", "Score"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["name_"+str(i) for i in range(2,7)], list(range(12,17))]).transpose()
df2.columns = ["Name", "Score"]
```

I want to join the dataframes such that all rows that are in `df1` are present in the result but wherever the `Name` values in `df1` are present in `df2`, the result should contain values from `df2`. Essentially, I want to update `df1` with values from `df2` wherever the `Name` the matches

This is what I am looking for

```
     Name  Score
0  name_0      0
1  name_1      1
2  name_2     12
3  name_3     13
4  name_4     14
5  name_5     15
6  name_6     16
7  name_7      7
8  name_8      8
9  name_9      9
```

Is there a way I can do this operation using a join operation. I was able to do this using an assignment operation

```
df1.loc[df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name']), "Score"] = df2["Score"].values
```

Is there a way I can do this using a join operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Name')
df2 = df2.set_index('Name')

df1.update(df2)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
     Name Score
0  name_0     0
1  name_1     1
2  name_2    12
3  name_3    13
4  name_4    14
5  name_5    15
6  name_6    16
7  name_7     7
8  name_8     8
9  name_9     9
```

---

> Is there a way I can do this using a join operation?

Yes, you can join together and then replace missing values with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
df = df1.join(df2.set_index('Name'), on='Name', lsuffix='_')
#merge alternative
#df = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left', suffixes=('_', ''))
df['Score'] = df['Score'].fillna(df.pop('Score_'))
print (df)
     Name  Score
0  name_0      0
1  name_1      1
2  name_2     12
3  name_3     13
4  name_4     14
5  name_5     15
6  name_6     16
7  name_7      7
8  name_8      8
9  name_9      9
```